# How to use custom init of ViewController in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, constructor, uistoryboard, init

I have one storyboard in which all of my viewControllers are placed. I'm using `StoryboardID` as:

```
AddNewPatientViewController * viewController =[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addNewPatientVC"];
 [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In `AddNewPatientViewController` I've added a custom init method or constructor you can say as:

```
-(id) initWithoutAppointment
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.roomBedNumberField.hidden = true;
    }
    return self;
}
```

So my question is by using the above wat of presenting view controller how can I `init` it with this custom `init` I've made.

I've tried doing this as areplacement of above code but it didn't work.

```
AddNewPatientViewController *viewController = [[AddNewPatientViewController alloc] initWithoutAppointment];
 [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Hi Talha, if you are using storyboard, maybe it would be cleaner solution to use storyboard segues and especially to customize your presenting controller in "prepareForSegue" method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the best idea to use this approach. At first, I want to suggest you to set this property after instantiation; it would be better

If you anyway want to make such constructor, you can place your code with instantiation to it, so it will look like

```
-(id) initWithoutAppointment
{
    self = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addNewPatientVC"];
    if (self) {
        self.roomBedNumberField.hidden = true;
    }
    return self;
}
```

but it won't be a good code

EDITED

May be it's the question of style, but I would rather prefer not to do this because view controller doesn't have to know about UIStoryboard; if you want to have such method, it would be better to move it to some separate factory.
If I chose to use this VC in other projects without Storyboard, or with storyboards, but with another name, it will be error-prone.

Comment: Make it class method with return type `instancetype` and it will be good code.

Comment: I agree with Cy. This should be a class factory method (class method that returns a new instance of the class). See my answer of overriding the designated initializer, `initWithCoder:`

Comment: It would be better to make class method (factory method e.g. createWithoutAppointment) instead of initWithout... I'm not sure but it seems that init ARC semantics is violated in your sample (no call to super init, and you are assigning self to an autoreleased object).

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a storyboard call a custom initializer.

You want to override `init(coder:)`. That's the initializer that gets called when a view controller is created from a storyboard (or from a nib, for that matter.)

Your code might look something like this:

#### Objective-C:

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder; {
    [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    //your init code goes here.
}
```

#### Swift:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder)  {
  //Your custom initialization code goes here.
  print("In \(#function)")
  aStringProperty = "A value"
  super.init(coder: coder)
}
```

Note that in Swift your initializer must assign values to all non-optional properties before you call super.init, and that you **must** call `super.init()` (or in this case, `super.init(coder:)`.